# How to filter data from method call in collector before added to map

Tags: java, java-stream

I have structure

```
interface Foo{
   List<Bar> getBars();
}

interface Bar{
   List<Number> getValues();
}
```

and list `List<Foo> foos`

What I want is to create map which will looks more or less like that, with excluding entries where foo does'n have bars or bar does not have values.

```
{
  fooid :{
              barId : bar
           }
}
```

obviously my first thought was to do

```
    foos.stream().filter(f->!f.getBars().isEmpty())
    .collect( Collectors.toMap(
        f->f.id(),
        f->f.getBars().stream().filter(b->!b.getValues().isEmpty())
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap( b->b.id(),b->b.getValues()                       
    ))));
```

problem is i'm calling method `getValues` twice and it's expensive method,
what will be best practice to handle calls like that?

Comment: What is `getValues()` and how come it does not depend in anything you are actually working on, that is, the `f` or `b`?

Comment: Instead of a stream you could use a for loop where you can save the return value of getValues() to a variable.  That way you will only need to call it once.

Comment: @BakonJarser  thanks, probably i will do it, i was just wonder can i do it with streams

Comment: @RealSkeptic sorry, i didn't realised i cut description of Bar,  in my code i'm passing bar to another function which evaluates into values, to simplified i put it on bar

Comment: Now I really don't know what you need and what the problem is, because this is code that would not compile. Please create a proper [mcve].

Comment: @RealSkeptic sorry i got bit sloppy, had a long day. i fixed code.

Comment: You example code does not "exclude entries where bar does not have values". If you have a `Foo` that contains a `Bar` that doesn't have any values, you will get an entry for it.

Comment: @user1803551 yes, thanks for noticing it. this is one of  the another issue which i want to deal with, but trully it can be same mechanism

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
private static void doMap(List<Foo> foos) {
    foos.stream()
        .filter(foo -> !foo.getBars()
                           .isEmpty())
        .map(foo -> new SimpleEntry<>(foo.getId(), foo.getBars()
                                                      .stream()
                                                      .map(bar -> new SimpleEntry<>(bar.getId(), bar.getValues()))
                                                      .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue()
                                                                             .isEmpty())
                                                      .collect(entriesToMapCollector())))
        .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().isEmpty())
        .collect(entriesToMapCollector());
}

private static <K, V> Collector<Entry<K, V>, ?, Map<K, V>> entriesToMapCollector() {
    return Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue);
}
```

(I would *strongly* advocate a more imperative approach to this for the sake of readability, maintainability and everything-ability - please don't do this in production code)

Comment: You solutions does not "exclude entries where bar does not have values". If you have a `Foo` that contains a `Bar` that doesn't have any values, you will get an entry for it.

Comment: It has a filter on `!entry.getValue().isEmpty` - only accepts those `Bar`'s into the collect that have values.

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: I did, but also happy to revisit if you've found a problem with it

Comment: Hold up I didn't copy/paste the final solution. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I spent ages trying to work out how to extract `entriesToMapCollector` into its own method because it's a pattern I use so often (and I am terrible at deriving generic types)... Took a look back at the solution and was like "where did all my hard work go?"). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you realize that what you're doing with a list of `Foo` and a list of `Bar` is the same operation, you can solve this problem more easily. This operation is a *groupingBy* where the `id` serves as the key and a `List` serves as the values. You add the condition that a mapping shouldn't be created if the values is an empty list.

This would have been a simple case of grouping the `Bar`s:

```
bars.stream()
    .filter(b -> !b.getValues().isEmpty())
    .collect(toMap(b -> b.id(), b -> b.getValues()));
```

and the `Foo`s:

```
foos.stream()
    .filter(f -> !f.getBars().isEmpty())
    .collect(toMap(f -> f.id(), f -> groupBars(f.getBars())));
```

where `groupBars` executes the first code block. The problem with grouping the `bars` this way is that you call `getValues` twice, which you mention is expensive. The problem with grouping the `foos` this way is that you filter before knowing if there will be a mapping to an empty value (the result of `groupBars`).

As shown in [*Not a JD*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55499081/1803551), a solution to both problems is caching/storing. For `Bar`s, you want to cache the result of `getValues`. For `Foo`s, you want to cache the result of `groupBars` so that you can filter on it. The way to cache in a stream is with a container object; in this case  `Map.Entry` works well, but you can use any data storing object. You then map you data into your object (getting a stream of these) and you are able to retrieve its data in different parts of the stream.

The following method groups a list of `Bar`s by their `id`:

```
static Map<Integer, List<Number>> groupByIdBar(List<Bar> bars) {
       return bars.stream()
                  .map(b -> Map.entry(b.id(), b.getValues()))
                  .filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
                  .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
}
```

where `e.getValue()` is the retrieval call from our "cache".

Similarly, this method will group `Foo`s by `id`:

```
static Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Number>>> groupByIdFoo(List<Foo> foos) {
       return foos.stream()
                  .map(f -> Map.entry(f.id(), groupByIdBar(f.getBars())))
                  .filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
                  .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
}
```

where `e.getValue()` is the result of `groupByIdBar`, which allows post-processing (filtering).

You'll notice that the methods are very similar. This is because, as stated in the beginning, we are performing the same operation on them.

The result you want is obtained by `groupByIdFoo(foos)`.

---

Looping might just be easier in this case:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Number>>> mapping = new HashMap<>();
for (Foo f : foos) {
    List<Bar> bars = f.getBars();
    if (!bars.isEmpty()) {
        Map<Integer, List<Number>> bMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Bar b : bars) {
            if (!b.getValues().isEmpty()) {
                bMap.put(b.id(), b.getValues());
            }
        }
        if (!bMap.isEmpty()) {
            mapping .put(f.id(), bMap);
        }
    }
}
```

If you choose to go this way, you can do some optimization to the code. For example, you can instantiate `bMap` on the first encounter with a non-empty `b.getValues()`.

---

For the dataset

```
Bar b1 = new Bar(1);
b1.values = List.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);

Bar b2 = new Bar(2);
b2.values = List.of();

Bar b3 = new Bar(3);
b3.values = List.of(60, 70);

Foo f1 = new Foo(11);
f1.bars = List.of(b1, b2, b3);

Foo f2 = new Foo(22);
f2.bars = List.of();

Foo f3 = new Foo(33);
f3.bars = List.of(b2);

Foo f4 = new Foo(44);
f4.bars = List.of(b1);

List<Foo> foos = List.of(f1, f2, f3, f4);
```

Both give the result:

```
{11={1=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 3=[60, 70]}, 44={1=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}}
```